# Session creation problem in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have to create a session inside the blade, but it doesn't respond at all. How can I do that?

```
@if($edit_mode)
    @foreach($features as $feature_add_count => $feature_value)
        @php
        if(!$feature_value->quick_view) session(['feature_id_'.$feature_value->feature_id => true]);
        @endphp
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Add some code to help you

Comment: where you print it in your code?

Comment: what "doesn't respond at all"? and why would you set these values from a view

Comment: Features previously added to the page on the blade side are printed on the screen in a loop. During the editing process, when adding a new feature to the page, I have this value checked with a session to prevent the same feature from being added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that session cannot be created in Blade. I solved the problem as follows; I created hidden type input and posted the value in these inputs when the page was loaded, and created the necessary session information on the controller side.

Answer (score -1):

you should use Session with Facades

```
@if($edit_mode)
@foreach($features as $feature_add_count => $feature_value)
    @if(!$feature_value->quick_view)
        {{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::put('feature_id_',$feature_value->feature_id) }}@endif @endforeach @endif
```

Comment: I've tried this before and tried everything